# Accessing wordField.Code gives runtime error "That property is not available on that object."

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, vsto

I am converting a VB6 project into C#. The project is an Word add-in(Word ribbon bar) and we are using Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) that and a class library project.

MyProject add macro enabled word fields(type : `Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldMacroButton`)  to the word document on ribbon bar item clicks (different types of macros).

As per [this article](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/vsto/calling-code-in-vsto-add-ins-from-other-office-solutions.md) , I have implemented to call code in VSTO add-in using VBA. 
I am using a macro enabled document template (myTemplate.dotm) to identify macro double click events.

I am currently implementing the Edit function (on double click of a macro field, edit dialog opens.)

Below is the functions of the RunSelectedFieldTagMacro() method which

1. Kill revision tracking
2. Get selected field tag
3. Run fieldtag Macro (edit function)
4. Restore revision tracking

Here I have a class called FieldTags which initialized using the active WordDocument.

```
internal FieldTags(Word.Document document){ //...}
```

There's a class called FieldTag initialized from wordField in the document. 
In FieldTags class, I am using `private List<FieldTag> fieldTagsList` to store the FieldTag objects identified at the `CollectionLoad()` method in the FieldTags class 
(I am using a List here, because I have to add newly added fieldtags to the word document into this collection as in order they are in the document.).

So my question,

I am double clicking on a fieldtag in the word document. So the VBA macro executes and via VSTO add-in, the RunSelectedFieldTagMacro() method in the class project.

In there, after loading the  `fieldTagsList`, edit function happens and MyProject add a new fieldTag right above the editing field tag (Here we do is, insert the new fieldtag, then delete the old one with its sub fields).

```
public FieldTag Add(Word.Range wordRange, Tag tag)
    {
        try
        {
            FieldTag fieldTag;
            Word.Field wordField;

            //Create a new field at the specified range.
            wordField = wordRange.Fields.Add(Range: wordRange, PreserveFormatting: false);

            //Insert the contents of the new field.
            tag.InsertFieldContents(wordField);

            //Field must be updated to display properly and for style to be correctly applied.
            wordField.Update();

            //Add a FieldTag to the Document.FieldTags collection.
            fieldTag = this.AddFieldTag(wordField);

            //Apply style to the new FieldTag.
            fieldTag.ApplyStyle();

            return fieldTag;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

At the "Add a FieldTag to the `Document.FieldTags collection`" part, we are checking the Item By RangeStart.

```
private FieldTag ItemByRangeStart()
{
    for (int i = fieldTagsList.Count; i > 1; i--)
    {
        fieldTag = fieldTagsList[i-1];

        if (rangeStart > fieldTag.WordField.Code.Start)
        {
            return fieldTag;
        }
    }   
}
```

By this time, the new field tag has been added to the document. At the loop, when checking the double clicked (editing) fieldtag,   `fieldTag.WordField.Code` throws the below error.

> fieldTag.WordField.Code threw an exception of type
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>
> That property is not available on that object.

When try running the edit function via word field tag double click, this error occurs. 
I can also run the field tag edit function via, Select the field tag and then run the `RunSelectedFieldTagMacro()` method via visual studio.But then this error doesn't occur.

Both processes running through the exactly same codes. The only difference is, at error occurring steps : I start by double clicking the field tag.
and when run through visual studio, I manually select the field tag range.

Does anybody have an idea why I am unable to access the wordField.Code after inserting the new fieldtag? I am really stuck in here.

Thank you in advance.

Note : I am unable to add all codes here, as there are lots of middle classes within this process. Hope you guys will understand what my question is.

Comment: This is really hard to follow, you need to reduce this to an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Where is your document located on the disk? Is it a system drive which requires admin privileges?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I checked opening the document as 'Run as administrator', but still has the issue. Also document is  just located in the desktop.

Comment: Which method or property exactly fires the exception?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev In the ItemByRangeStartMethod, fieldTag.WordField.Code throws the exception. I am unable to access the wordField.Code part only for the editing field tag (the field tag that I double clicked). 
Can double click & single click( that also selects the field tag) create such error?

Comment: I'd recommend breaking the chain of property and method calls. There are two points in the single line of code.